# Perl: Using Net::Google::Spreadsheets gives error in libxml

Tags: perl, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use Perl google spreadsheet API and i am getting stuck in this error. I did exactly as per the doc at http://search.cpan.org/~danjou/Net-Google-Spreadsheets-0.1501/lib/Net/Google/Spreadsheets.pm

Here is the code

```
use Net::Google::Spreadsheets;
use Net::Google::DataAPI::Auth::OAuth2;
use Net::OAuth2::AccessToken;

my $oauth2;
my $service;

$oauth2 = Net::Google::DataAPI::Auth::OAuth2->new(
  client_id => '<clientid>',
  client_secret => '<client secret>',
  scope => ['http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/'],
);

my $url = $oauth2->authorize_url(
     access_type => 'offline',
     approval_prompt => 'force',
);

print "$url\nEnter the code: ";
my $code = <STDIN>;
my $access_token = $oauth2->get_access_token($code) or die;

$service = Net::Google::Spreadsheets->new(auth => $oauth2);

print "Testing Spreadsheet";
# find a spreadsheet by key
my $spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheet( { key => '<spread sheet key>' }) or die $!;
```

It does not throw error during Oauth but when I try to access the spreadsheet API it gives me the following error.

> Use of uninitialized value $nsURI in string eq at
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/mach/XML/LibXML.pm line 1705. 
>   at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/mach/XML/LibXML.pm line 1699.
>           XML::LibXML::Element::getElementsByTagNameNS(XML::LibXML::Element=SCALAR(0x80416ed20),
>   undef, "entry") called at
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/XML/Atom/Feed.pm line 84
>           XML::Atom::Feed::entries_libxml(XML::Atom::Feed=HASH(0x8041938e8))
>   called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/Net/Google/DataAPI.pm
>   line 113
>           Net::Google::Spreadsheets::spreadsheets(Net::Google::Spreadsheets=HASH(0x803045600),
>   HASH(0x802a5cb70)) called at
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/Net/Google/Spreadsheets.pm line
>   57
>           Net::Google::Spreadsheets::**ANON**(CODE(0x803020438), Net::Google::Spreadsheets=HASH(0x803045600), HASH(0x802a5cb70)) called
>   at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/mach/Mouse/Meta/Class.pm line
>   381
>           Mouse::Meta::Class::**ANON**(Net::Google::Spreadsheets=HASH(0x803045600),
>   HASH(0x802a5cb70)) called at
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/mach/Mouse/Meta/Class.pm line
>   334
>           Net::Google::Spreadsheets::spreadsheets(Net::Google::Spreadsheets=HASH(0x803045600),
>   HASH(0x802a5cb70)) called at
>   /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.2/Net/Google/DataAPI.pm line 132
>           Net::Google::Spreadsheets::spreadsheet(Net::Google::Spreadsheets=HASH(0x803045600),
>   HASH(0x802a5cb70)) called at try.pl line 62

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem here is the solution.

Looks like between the time when this module was written and today google has changed their API so the documentation of the module needs to be modified.

By changing the key => 'the key' to id => 'the key' solved the problem.

So the correct way to get the spreadsheet would be

```
my $spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheet( { id => '<spread sheet key>' }) or die 
$!;
```

The key is part of the url
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[spreadsheetkey]/edit